# How to clear logs on WebLogic Server console without turning off server?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I am trying to clear Web logic server console logs, to check latest logs without turning off server.

I have tried to clear logs by pressing "Ctrl+C" on console, but not working and logs was not cleared from console.

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible. Why don't you directly read log files instead of reading the console output ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I can directly read log files from console itself but my problem is, there was huge no.of logs displaying for every small event(transaction), That's why I want to clear old logs to check only latest event logs for the latest events(transactions).

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Mac, use `cmd + k` to clear the logs and check the latest ones.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am using Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should not run Weblogic using the Command Prompt because if someone closes the console the service is going to crash. With this in mind, you should configure the your servers as service on Windows so please read this document.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13708/winservice.htm#START144

The Dude